# ASHX file Parser error - could not create type

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, ashx

I got a sample application to install on IIS from a vendor that I am testing for making barcodes.

The aspx pages work fine, but when the aspx page calls the ashx page, I get the error below:

> ### Server Error in '/BarcodeSample' Application.
>
> Parser Error  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not create type
>   'TECIT.OnlineBarcodes.BarcodeHandler'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#"
>   CodeBehind="BarcodeHandler.ashx.cs"
>   Class="TECIT.OnlineBarcodes.BarcodeHandler" %>
>
> Source File: /BarcodeSample/BarcodeHandler.ashx    Line: 1
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3634;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3634

Why is this happening? How can I get this ashx file to work?

Comment: Is it a "Website" or a "Web Application"?  i.e, when you look in the list of files in the source folder, do you see both "BarcodeHandler.ashx" *and* "BarcodeHandler.ashx.cs" as source files?  If not, is there some `.dll` file containing compiled files included in the `/bin/` folder of the application?

Comment: It's a website. All I did was make a virtual directory under the default website and point it to the sample app location.

Comment: Did you make the virtual directory a full-blown application as well?

Comment: I didn't but it is anyway. Went into the virtual directory properties and it has a value for Application name (BarcodeSample) which I assume means it is a full blown application.

Comment: Also, the application runs ok in VS. I opened it up in VS and it builds and runs ok. Which means it's not just simple namespace mistake or typo somewhere...

Answer (score 13):

Check the full name of the class starting from the namespace (if used). I had the same issue and it was fixed after changing the class name like this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Namespace.ClassName" %>
```

instead of this:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ClassName" %>
```

Comment: this worked for me ; you have to edit the .ashx file manually and fix the attribut Class="" to indicate the namespace and your class name

Answer (score 5):

A simple workaround that I found works:

- Put the .ashx.cs code after the first line of the .ashx file
- Remove the CodeBehind attribute on the first line of the .ashx file
- Remove the Code behind file

Comment: Having the .ashx.cs file separate worked fine for me in dev.  But my production server would always throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

Add below tag

```
<%@ Assembly  Name="YourNameSpace.YourHandlerClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=90e3045b123af1c3" %>
```

above your WebHandler tag

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="BarcodeHandler.ashx.cs" Class="TECIT.OnlineBarcodes.BarcodeHandler" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with the naming of the namespace, so I had to edit the `example.ashx` file (not the `example.ashx.cs`) and change the namespace name there.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my handler through the solution explorer.

VS2017 suggested changeing the name only in .cs file, and left the class attribute in the ashx file incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on your generic handler in Solution Explorer, then press F4 for "Properties".  Make sure your **build action** is "compile", not just "content".